# How to match ".js" and ".css" but exclude ".min.js" and ".min.css"?

Tags: regex

I tried the following without success:

```
\.(?!min)(js|css)$
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/qV1sD7/1)

I'm not very familiar with negative lookaheads, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

How can my regex be modified to match `.js` and `.css` but exclude `.min.js` and `.min.css`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got it quite right, except

- you need to place it before the dot
- you need to use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of lookahead

```
(?<!\.min)\.(js|css)$
```

With lookahead this is more complicated, altough you might manage it if you matched the complete filename:

```
^(.{0,3}|.*(?!\.min).{4})\.(js|css)$
```

<sub>(a string shorter than 4 characters or one whose last 4 characters are not `.min`, isn't this horrible?)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You need to use negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\.min)\.(js|css)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qV1sD7/2)